# the_content() not working in my Android mobile

Tags: the-content, mobile

I have got a little problem. I am working in a theme developed by someone I don´t know.

I was testing the site in my cellphone and saw the_content() function does not show anything. I checked in one Ipad and it's working.

I also checked my functions.php and I did not see anything weird.

This is the link (sorry because it is Spanish site):

http://decopeques.com/local-infantil/thanks-mum/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!
Frede

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of javascript errors, try fixing them. Also, add the code that generates the page. The function `the_content()` doesn't care if it's a phone, or not, except you are also using the `is_mobile`function.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked this and it is indeed caused by the backend.

Your website doesn't show the content when it detects a mobile user agent. You should first check the theme options. Otherwise it might be caused by a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not responding earlier, I was running out of time. I step out here for 5 minutes just to let you know I fixed the issue and thank you for your suggestions, really useful!

I found this piece of code in the header.php

```
<?php if (wpbasic_is_mobile(true)): ?>
<?php
the_post();
$data = get_data_posts(get_the_id());
endif; ?>
```

To be honest I don´t know why he coded that but I don´t care at all since I deleted and now it's working :D

Frede